# 'The Russia-Ukraine border' v. 'the Russia-Ukrainian border' v. 'the Russian-Ukrainian border'

Tags: phrase-request

Is it, for example, 'the Russia-Ukraine border', or 'the Russia-Ukrainian border', or 'the Russian-Ukrainian border'? How do I specify what countries it separates? Also, is there any rule or convention on which country goes first (i.e. 'the Russian-Ukrainian border' or 'the Ukrainian-Russian border')?

Comment: I believe all of those options are acceptable in everyday prose. For journalistic purposes, publishers will have their own style manual to follow, and they may not all agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of *style of expression*. All these are correct : 'the Russia-Ukraine border', or 'the Russia-Ukrainian border', or 'the Russian-Ukrainian border'.

Even *'the Russo-Ukranian border'* is also ok.